# Is ActivityDate a known bug with bulk API loading tasks?

Tags: api, error, tasks, bulk-api, simple-salesforce

I've been fighting Salesforce all morning with a data load via the Python simple_salesforce package *(so yes, the bug could be there, rather than there being an issue in the Bulk API)*.

If I run this code, everything goes fine:

```
sf.Task.upsert(
    'External_ID__c/'+'12345'
    , {
          "WhoId": "003aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
          , "Subject": "AAAAAAA"
          , "ActivityDate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"
          , "Status": "Completed"
          , "Priority": "Normal"
          , "Description": "A A A A A A A"
          , "Type": ""
          , "ReminderDateTime": ""
          , "IsReminderSet": 0
    }
)
```

However, if I run this code, the batch fails with an `InvalidBatch` exception code:

```
sf.bulk.Task.upsert(
    [
        {
              "External_Id__c" : "12345"
              , "WhoId": "003aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
              , "Subject": "AAAAAAA"
              , "ActivityDate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"
              , "Status": "Completed"
              , "Priority": "Normal"
              , "Description": "A A A A A A A"
              , "Type": ""
              , "ReminderDateTime": ""
              , "IsReminderSet": 0
        }
        , {
              "External_Id__c" : "98765"
              , "WhoId": "003bbbbbbbbbbbbb"
              , "Subject": "BBBBBBBBB"
              , "ActivityDate": "2020-03-03T00:00:00Z"
              , "Status": "Completed"
              , "Priority": "Normal"
              , "Description": "B B B B B B B"
              , "Type": ""
              , "ReminderDateTime": ""
              , "IsReminderSet": 0
        }
    ]
    , 'External_ID__c'
)
```

When I leave out `ActivityDate`, it works:

```
sf.bulk.Task.upsert(
    [
        {
              "External_Id__c" : "12345"
              , "WhoId": "003aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
              , "Subject": "AAAAAAA"
              , "Status": "Completed"
              , "Priority": "Normal"
              , "Description": "A A A A A A A"
              , "Type": ""
              , "ReminderDateTime": ""
              , "IsReminderSet": 0
        }
        , {
              "External_Id__c" : "98765"
              , "WhoId": "003bbbbbbbbbbbbb"
              , "Subject": "BBBBBBBBB"
              , "Status": "Completed"
              , "Priority": "Normal"
              , "Description": "B B B B B B B"
              , "Type": ""
              , "ReminderDateTime": ""
              , "IsReminderSet": 0
        }
    ]
    , 'External_ID__c'
)
```

Is there a known issue with bulk-loading Task records and the ActivityDate field?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Seems the record-by-record REST API is tolerant of `ActivityDate` values with a timestamp, but the Bulk API is not.

Bulk works with the body saying `"ActivityDate": "2020-03-03"`

Comment: The [Task docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) mention that the timestamp is not relevant for ActivityDate and always set to midnight in UTC time zone. Not sure why it works in one way vs. the other though.